# Database structure for WarGames - Players - Rewards

Tags: database-design, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle11gr2

**Context** :- *My clan regularly play online PvP tournaments and get rewarded with in-game currency and sometimes real money depending on result. I need to keep track of who participated on which date. 
I have created a Table which contains the player data which is to be updated if someone joins or leaves my clan.
Each war game is 15 v 15.
We play 4 war games daily, each have upto 7 battles involving players from my team  and  opponents.
So that's*  **15 entries per war game per day**.

**My question**

1- How to design a table that can keep track of the war games, date and time, result and players involved.

2- Depending on the above mentioned table , i would need to distribute rewards as well and keep track of those. More participated more rewards.

I am using Oracle 11g for my database.

Comment: It's not going to be just one table. It will be a series of tables to make up a data model. If you're set on one table, I'd recommend just using Excel instead. Also, please remove the sql-server tag, if this is for Oracle.

Comment: I am down for series of tables. This would be a great opportunity to learn. I maintain Excel but want to do this in Database so i can get more practice. This will be my real time scenario.

Comment: Look up data modeling.  Generally, you want your table information to relate to the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key, so help you Codd.

Comment: I started teaching myself sql in December. So i am very new to databases. I have Oracle 11g installed in my pc. Will oracle developer data modeler be a good choice. I have to learn how to use it.

Comment: Database modeling is not linked to the database software you use.  Any RDBMS will do.  To get started, look at how to split your requirements into objects (tables) and the links between those (foreign keys and link tables).  Then look into normal forms.  Usually forms 1, 2 and 3 are sufficient for most applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup tables like this:

### Player

```
idPlayer    PK
Name
cell#
email
... other fields that define a player
```

### Clan

```
idClan      PK
Name
```

### ClanAsPlayer

```
idClan      FK Clan.idClan
idPlayer    FK Player.idPlayer
```

### WarGames

```
idWarGame   PK
Date
Time
```

### Battle

```
WarGames   FK WarGames.idWarGame
Winner     FK Player.idPlayer
Looser     FK Player.idPlayer
```

### Reward

```
idReward    PK
Reward      <-- what the reward is
```

### PlayerAsReward

```
idPlayer    FK Player.idPlayer
idReward    FK Reward.idReward
```

- Player: not using the name as the primary key, since 2 players could have the same name
- Clan: what clans you have.  If you have only one (yours), it could be a simple field in the Player table
- ClanAsPlayer: to link Players to Clans.  If there is only one clan, forget that table.
- Battle: there are many battles in a WarGame.  So link the WarGame to each Battle entry.  Since a battle cannot be linked to more than one WarGame, you just link the WarGame into the Battle.
- To know which players were present in a WarGame, you query through the Battle link table
- OR if you can have players present in a WarGame even if do not participate in battles, you could add a link table WarGamesAsPlayer.
- PlayerAsReward: this table must be filled by the application, based on some logic you implement
- You use link tables (like PlayerAsReward) when you have a n to n relationship between tables.  Like this one, any player can have any rewards.

This can get you started in a database designer or modelization software.

Comment: Thank you. But how do i stire the team list. It's 15 v 15. 15 from my clan vs another clan. I have to store the names of all(my team) who participated. Probably have to use 15 columns in Battle table.

Comment: Since you have 15 players in your clan, simply have 15 lines in the Battle table.  Each line represents a single 1 to 1 combat.  You will reap the benefits of such a method when you decide to have 10 or 20 players later.  It is much easier to add a line in a table, than add new columns.  Adding lines is a simple query, adding columns forces you to change the table structure, and possibly some queries in your application.

Comment: Why didn't i think of that. I am so stupid. I can just add the date and time to identify the battle as that will always be unique. Thank you

Comment: Actually the date and time is already defined in the WarGame table.  Battles are linked to a single WarGame, hence giving you the date time :-)